# How to save a dynamic html page which displays results of tests written in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dynamic html page `index.html`.

When I hit that page in the browser it runs some tests which is written in *JS* and generates dynamic results on the page. On every reload it writes fresh data on index.html page.

Now I want to save this html page into another html page so that I can save the results and view later.

Comment: Open console: `document.documentElement.outerHTML` → **copy** → **paste**

Answer (score 1):

One method of doing it would be to write the dynamic results to an element on the page, and then save the contents of that via an ajax call.

For example create an element with an ID `results` on your `index.html` page:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

Write the dynamic results to this element. I'm going to write the js in jquery syntax for brevity; but you can adapt this to vanilla js:

```
$('#results').html(data); // data is the dynamic content
```

Now you can grab the data inside `#results` and make an ajax call to a script which could write it to a HTML file:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/save-data.php', // script to save your data
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            results: $('#results').val() // the html inside #results
        }
    });
});
```

Your `save-data.php` script would read the contents in the POST variable (`$_POST['results']`) and then write it to a file, e.g.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('data.html', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $_POST['results']);
?>
```

**This is merely to illustrate the concepts required.** You need to take care of security, particularly sanitising the POST data.

The js to make the ajax call will execute on page load of `index.html`. You could adapt this to work when the user presses a button or takes some other action. You may also want to look at the `.done()` method in jquery because this is where you could perform checks to see if `save-data.php` has actually saved the data and display an appropriate message.

For example `save-data.php` might return a JSON response on successfully saving the data:

```
echo json_encode(['result' => 'success']);
```

You could then use the `.done()` callback to display an appropriate message to the user when the data has been saved:

```
 // previous ajax code
 // ...
.done(function(response) {
    if (response.result == 'success') {
        // write message to the page to say it's been done successfully
        // You will need an element with the class .status to hold the message, e.g. <span class="status"></span>
        $('.status').html('Successfully saved your page').
    }
});
```